# initialization and $watch in angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, initialization

A Part of my Page is handled by a controller. It depends on the global property $scope.selected. I have to initialize the controller at controller startup and whenever the value of $scope.selected changes.

```
.controller ('Details', ['$scope',  function ($scope) {
  function init () {
    $scope.viewProperty = complexOperation($scope.selected);
  }
  $scope.$watch ('selected', init);
  init ();
}])

<span ng-if="selected.gto" ng-controller="Details">
    {{viewProperty}}
</span>
```

I call init on controller initialization and on changes of $scope.selected.
This doesn't look nice for me, is there a better solution?

Comment: `init()` will be called by the watch anyway on controller initialization. You can check this with a `console.log` inside `init()`. So, the last `init()` statement in your controller is redundant.

Comment: No, thats not true, my karma test fails if I omit the call to init().

Comment: Maybe you should check the test... make sure it calls `$apply` or `$digest`.

Comment: I call $controller, I think there must be a call of $digest.

Comment: I included console.log statements, when I run the app in the browser there is only one call of init, too.

Answer (score 0):

`$watch()` is generally used inside a directive instead of a controller. Also like the comment has mentioned `init()` is called once when the controller initialized, since [$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope) calls its listener once when initializing. Here is an article about this practice [Angular JS - you probably shouldn't use $watch in your controllers.](http://www.benlesh.com/2013/10/title.html)

Comment: Excellent point and link. Only thing I'd add is that `ng-change` should be used from the DOM to indicate a change within the controller (even though no DOM references were made in the question)

Comment: I do agree with Lenny's comment in the linked article. I am using the $watch to decouple controllers from each other. The global controller sets a property and has not to call a function of the inner controller.

Comment: what I am looking for is something like <any ng-controller="...,reload-on-change-of=someProperty">